# In Review : Question which have closed should redirect to next question on click on popup cross mark

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

Here, I was reviewing the close vote queue, Question was already closed and I clicked on close button and it says message "to refresh the page for updated status". , I know this is not bad but not good to say user to refresh a whole page. You guys can manage this easily in web programming.

[image]

Here in this situation , either system should redirect to next question on click on cross mark and should show only "Next" button behind this `jquery` pop up without loading complete page.